# Finding no. of working days in a month till sysdate/ today's date is it is current month

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using the following query to find out the number of working days in a month excluding the weekends

```
select payroll_id as payrollId,
(select count(*) 
from ( select rownum rnum 
from all_objects 
where rownum <= to_date(to_char(last_day(to_date('01-'||'MAY'||'2017','DD-MM-YYYY')),'DD')||'MAY'||'2017','DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date('01-'||'MAY'||'2017','DD-MM-YYYY')+1 ) 
where to_char( to_date('01-'||'MAY'||'2017','DD-MM-YYYY')+rnum-1, 'DY' ) 
not in ( 'SAT', 'SUN' )) - (select count(*) from admin_holiday where to_char(holiday_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') like '%-MAY-2017%' and holiday_type_id=1) days
from employee where DEL_FLAG=1 order by payrollId
```

Here, payrollId is the employee_id in employee table and admin_holiday is a table that contains information about the national holidays in a month

My requirement is that if the month is current month then the working days should be upto today's date. For example the current month is MAY/2017 and till today(i.e 22/05/2017) the working days count excluding weekends is 15 (10/05/2017 is a national holiday according to Hindu calendar.

How do I obtain the required result.

***NOTE*** this action has to be performed in a single select statement and no other pl/sql blocks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach the equivalent query. By placing the date range calculation into a small cross joined query you can access the result easily throughout the remainder of the query.

```
SELECT
     e.payroll_id AS payrollId
  ,  cj. working_days
FROM employee e
cross join (
        select
             GREATEST(NEXT_DAY(start_date, 'MON') - start_date - 2, 0) 
            + ((NEXT_DAY(end_date, 'MON') - NEXT_DAY(start_date, 'MON'))/7)*5
            - GREATEST(NEXT_DAY(end_date, 'MON') - end_date - 3, 0) 
            - (
                  SELECT COUNT(holiday) 
                  FROM admin_holiday
                  WHERE holiday_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
               ) 
              as working_days
        FROM (
              select
                 to_date('20170501','yyyymmdd')  as start_date
               , to_date('20170522','yyyymmdd')  as end_date
              from dual
            )
        ) cj
WHERE e.DEL_FLAG = 1
ORDER BY e.payrollId
```

The working days logic is:

Calculate leading days in first week + (Count the number on mon/fri periods) * 5 - number of trailing days in final week - the additional holidays in a table:

```
select
      GREATEST(NEXT_DAY(start_date, 'MON') - start_date - 2, 0) 
    + ((NEXT_DAY(end_date, 'MON') - NEXT_DAY(start_date, 'MON'))/7)*5
    - GREATEST(NEXT_DAY(end_date, 'MON') - end_date - 3, 0) 
    - (
          SELECT COUNT(holiday) 
          FROM admin_holiday
          WHERE holiday_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
       ) 
      as working_days
    , start_date
    , end_date
    , holidays
    , end_date - start_date
FROM (
      select
         trunc(sysdate,'MM')  as start_date
       , trunc(sysdate)       as end_date
      from dual
    )
```

example (not there is zero holidays here):

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
| WORKING_DAYS | START_DATE   | END_DATE    | HOLIDAYS   |   END_DATE-START_DATE   |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
|           16 |  01.05.2017  | 22.05.2017  |          0 |                      21 |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
```

To manually set the dates you can do this:

```
select
      GREATEST(NEXT_DAY(start_date, 'MON') - start_date - 2, 0) 
    + ((NEXT_DAY(end_date, 'MON') - NEXT_DAY(start_date, 'MON'))/7)*5
    - GREATEST(NEXT_DAY(end_date, 'MON') - end_date - 3, 0) 
    - (
          SELECT COUNT(holiday) 
          FROM admin_holiday
          WHERE holiday_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
       ) 
      as working_days
FROM (
      select
         to_date('20170501','yyyymmdd')  as start_date
       , to_date('20170522','yyyymmdd')  as end_date
      from dual
    )
```

Comment: Exactly where do I make changes in your query  for corresponding dates, because this gives me the following error--                                             ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected" . I replaced start_date by 01-MAY-2017 and end_date by 31-MAY-2017 in select clause

Comment: In the rows that end with "as start_date" and "as end_date" ; I don't know how to make it more obvious I'm afraid.

Comment: Just in case you needed to see how my logic applies to your original query I have added a further part of my answer (at the top). I trust you will take the time to respond (as I have done for you).

Comment: I am getting appropriate results in some cases while in others I am getting +1 more than actual count should be. Could you please tell me what could be the reason ?

Comment: Will you add sample data and expected results please

Comment: Solved now. There was some issue with holiday column.

Comment: Excellent. Anything else needed before the answer is marked as correct?